# How should I deal with large datasets

Tags: c, memory

I want to maximize likelihood function *L* of the form

*L(\theta, x_1,  \ldots, x_13) = \sum_{k = 1}^13 l_k(x_k)*

with respect to $\theta$, where *x_k*'s is a large datasets (roughly 9GB each).

I have a code C that computes each of the *l_k* functions independently. For each iteration of the numerical optimizer I have to load each of the *x_k* again because my computer wont load all of them simultaneously. It complains about memory.

Currently, the code is written so that *x_k*'s and other large arrays are stored as global variables.

Also, I have been working on parallelizing, but I am not sure what's the best way to do it (I could parallelize the computation of *l_k*'s or a loop within the *l_k*'s), I have read that working with global variables is net. recommended when parallelizing.

Any suggestions??

Sorry about the math...

Comment: Let's see your C code. Please create a [mre].

Comment: You can convert your latex to image  with https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php and post the picture here. stackoverflow doesn't support latex maths.

Comment: @KamilCuk Most people don't support LaTeX equations, so if it's coming down to an equation, it's probably off-topic here. We need C code!

Comment: Translating this I get "I have a number of 9GB files that I need to process where each file needs to be compared to every other file. How can I do this efficiently? Loading more than two files at once consumes too much memory, so parallelizing this seems impractical." Is that right?